# Using alot MUA with nottoomuch-addresses

Tags: bash, email, command

I try to use the MUA *alot* to work with the `nottoomuch-addresses.sh` script for auto-completion of addresses within a lot like described in: http://alot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/contacts_completion.html

```
[[[abook]]]
      type = shellcommand
      command = nottoomuch-addresses.sh
      regexp = \"(?P<name>.+)\"\s*<(?P<email>.*.+?@.+?)>
      ignorecase = True
```

When I try the auto-completition within alot it gives me the error message:
`completition error: abook command "nottoomuch-addresses.sh" returned with return code 2`

As it is only a script and not a shell command I tried to giv the whole PATH to the script and I tried to move the script into the a lot configuration folder but the problem remains the same.

So I wonder what to do.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
[[[abook]]]
type = shellcommand
command = nottoomuch-addresses.sh
regexp = '"(?P<name>.+?)" <(?P<email>.+?)>'
ignorecase = True
```